# Remote install script and generate log files when failed to install?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to modify and fix this script below, so it can install the software in my domain controllers from my Powershell ISE Run as Administrator (With Enterprise Admins credentials)

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object {
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $_
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        Try {
            Write-Host "Processing Server ... $($Using:_)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            
                

$process = Start-Process -FilePath "AgentUpdate-x64.exe /s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files\Software1\" LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_ENABLED=True LOG_SOURCE_AUTO_CREATION_PARAMETERS=""&Component1.LogSourceIdentifier=%COMPUTERNAME%" -Wait -PassThru
    $process.ExitCode


        }
        Catch {
            Write-Warning -Message "Cannot Install the software on $($Using:_)"
            Write-Warning -Message $Error[0].Exception.Message
        }
    }
    Remove-PSSession $session
}
```

Note: the file AgentUpdate-x64.exe is MSI installer but with the .EXE extension, not .MSI

The error code is:

```
At line:25 char:245
+ ... REATION_PARAMETERS=""Component1.AgentDevice=DeviceWindowsLog&Componen ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:25 char:270
+ ... onent1.AgentDevice=DeviceWindowsLog&Component1.Action=create&Componen ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:25 char:310
+ ... onent1.Action=create&Component1.LogSourceName=%COMPUTERNAME%&Componen ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:25 char:356
+ ... %COMPUTERNAME%&Component1.LogSourceIdentifier=%COMPUTERNAME%&Componen ...
```

The problem is that it does not show any progress and I do not see the completion when it is successful or even failed with SERVERNAME-SoftwareName.LOG?

Comment: Take a look at start-process with the arguments -Wait and -PassThru

Comment: @guiwhatsthat yes, I have updated the code with the error message just now.

Comment: The errorcode is pretty obvious. & is a special character. The error is also showing you the solution: wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.

Comment: I did that already by Edit & Replace all ”&” but still the error persist ?

Comment: You can not add parameters to the -filepath parameter. Read the documentation of start-process. Check -argumentlist